# Javascript OOP - inheritance, prototyping, callback function

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, callback

I'm trying to use OOP in Javascript with inheritance, prototyping and callback functions. Would you please have a look at my JSfiddel http://jsfiddle.net/Charissima/5g6GV/.
The first problem is solved already in [Javascript OOP - inheritance and prototyping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431042/javascript-oop-inheritance-and-prototyping/19443839#19443839), but unfortunately the callback functions don't work any more.

```
        function Car () {    
            this.totalDistance = 0;
        };

        Car.prototype.putTotalDistance = function(distance) {
            this.totalDistance = distance;
        };

        Car.prototype.getTotalDistance = function() {
            return this.totalDistance;      
        };  

        Car.prototype.drive = function(distance) {
            this.totalDistance += distance;     
            return this.totalDistance;
        };


        function RaceCar () {};
        RaceCar.prototype = new Car();
        RaceCar.prototype.parent = Car.prototype;
        RaceCar.prototype.drive = function(distance) {
            return this.parent.drive.call(this, (distance * 2));
        };                     

        var myText;
        car = new Car;
        raceCar = new RaceCar;          

        car.putTotalDistance(200);
        myText = 'car totalDistance = ' + car.drive(10) + ' - ok<br>';

        raceCar.putTotalDistance(200);
        myText += 'raceCar totalDistance before drive = ' + raceCar.getTotalDistance() + ' - ok<br>';
        myText += 'raceCar totalDistance after drive = ' + raceCar.drive(10) + ' - ok<br><br>';                                                     

        car.putTotalDistance(0);            
        raceCar.putTotalDistance(100);
        var drivingFunctions = [car.drive, raceCar.drive];

        myText += drivingFunctions[0](10) + '<br>';
        try {
            myText += drivingFunctions[1](100) + '<br>';        
        }
        catch(err) {
            myText += err + + '<br>'
        }

        document.body.innerHTML = myText;
```

Comment: I don't see any use of callbacks in your code. Please state the actual problem more clearly directly in your question rather than relying on a link to another site (jsfiddle isn't always available). Describe the desired behaviour and the actual behaviour. What does "don't work any more" actually mean, e.g., is there an error in the browser's console, or does nothing happen, or does something happen but it's the wrong thing?

Comment: I don't want to use direct calls, but put the functions in an array:
var drivingFunctions = [car.drive, raceCar.drive];
The first is for the base class, the second for the inherited class.
Now I call drivingFunctions[0](10) and the result is NaN because this.totalDistance is undefined and I don't know why.

Comment: ... Then I call drivingFunctions[1](100) and even worth, I get an exception with the error text "this.parent is undefined".
I hope my explanation was clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put the two functions in an array, so when called, `this` get changed. 
You could use function `bind` :

```
   var drivingFunctions = [car.drive.bind(car), raceCar.drive.bind(raceCar)];
```

Here is an example to help you understand:

```
function Man(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.getName = function(){
      return this.name;  
    };
}
var man = new Man('toto');
var a = [man.getName];
console.log(a[0]());//undefined
a.name = 'titi';
console.log(a[0]());//titi, because this refers to the array.
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it resolves the OP's problem. However the problem is moot: I can't see a real-world scenario where you would  object method calls in an array without resorting to more effective and elegant solutions that don't mess with `this` contexts.

Comment: @JoeMinichino you are right, I just show the OP where the problem is.

Comment: on this topic i wrote a little library that messes with `this` contexts ***on purpose*** , check it out [here](https://github.com/techfort/paladin)